# Why Github code file is not showing fully

Tags: github

I am trying to open a github repository but it is showing only partly. The link to the repository is [here](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/04_training_linear_models.ipynb). I opened it yesterday and it has been showed fully but I am trying to open it since morning and it is not rendering properly to me. I have checked my Internet connection and it is perfect. Any suggestions. I am in desperate need. Thanks in advance

[image: The repository is showing upto here]

the image shows that the repository is visible upto here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem. It is better addressed the technical support department of your LAN / your ISP / Github.

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce this. The linked page renders completely for me. Try another browser.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This was my browser problem. Now I changed to Microsoft Edge and it runs perfect.